# Subdomain is taking over requests to domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I've created a subdomain called `mobile` for my website throuch **cPanel**. I redirect mobile devices to that subdomain, but there is javascript that lives there that makes AJAX calls to the actual domain. I have structured these calls to go to `website.com/mobile/...`. However, these aren't going through, and I suspect that it's because it is looking for `...` in my `/mobile`, but the request is supposed to be rewritten in **.htaccess** to `website.com/index.php?params=mobile/...`.

Here's the .htaccess:

```
# redirect phones/tablets to mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mobile\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mobile.website.com/$1 [L,R=302]

# not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# website.com/home => website.com/index.php?params=home
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\?.+)?$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works on my local machine but not on the live server. I have created a sudomain locally via

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/website/mobile"
    ServerName mobile.website.local
</VirtualHost>
```

and it works perfectly: when I go to `mobile.website.local` or `website.local/mobile`, I get the mobile site, and when I go to `website.local/mobile/users/login` I get the correct JSON output for the AJAX request.

How can I keep my `mobile` subdomain alive in `/mobile/` but have requests to `website.com/mobile/...` be forwarded with the last rewrite rule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the specific redirect for your /mobile, forcing to ignore the file or directory statement:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mobile [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\?.+)?$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]

# redirect phones/tablets to mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mobile\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^params=mobile(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mobile.website.com/$1 [L]

# not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# website.com/home => website.com/index.php?params=home
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\?.+)?$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Anything let me know and I'll see if I can help :)

Comment: Thanks for the response :) Unfortunately, the request still isn't going through. I tried putting that redirect before my other redirects, too, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Hello, i've been making some tests and it looks to work, are you putting the code before the file/directory statement? I'll make some more tests and i'll be replying to you soon.

Comment: Hello @Garrett, can you test the htaccess file again? I just edited my post with a new file.

Comment: I've tried it again with no luck. I'm in my iPhone's Safari with debug on. No errors, but the ajax request fails.